# Using Excel to find number of a duplicate in column

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to show the count of a duplicate within a given column. I can count how MANY duplicates there are within the column, but I want to know if this row is the first duplicate found, second, etc. Here's some sample data (sorted) and how I'd like it to appear:

```
1: ALPHA | 1
2: ALPHA | 2
3: DELTA | 1
4: ECHO  | 1
5: ECHO  | 2
6: ECHO  | 3
7: HOTEL | 1
8: HOTEL | 2
```

It doesn't matter if VBA is needed or it can be done in a formula, I just can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'duplicate number' of a given row is the number of entries equal to the current entry, in the range from the top of the column to the current row. This is actually easier to say in a formula than in English :)

If your example data is in two columns, and starts at `A1`, insert

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A8, A8)
```

into `B8`, and copy all the way up.

Comment: That formula gives me how many duplicates there are in the whole array. In my example, it puts a "2" in BOTH rows 1 and 2 for the second column.... which is not what I need.

Comment: It shouldn't do. By 'copy up', I mean to let Excel do its intelligent formula adjusting process. So you should end up with `=COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1)` in `B1`, `=COUNTIF(A$1:A2, A2)` in `B2`, and so on. Which give `1` and `2` respectively.

Comment: Make sure the $ is only on the first part of the range.

Comment: Ah! I see... it worked! Thank you. Such a simple solution that I'm mad at myself for not thinking of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indirect` to generate a reference from the results of other formulas, e.g.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("R1C"&(COLUMN()-1)&":R"&ROW()&"C"&(COLUMN()-1),FALSE), A1)
```

Comment: I put this formula in column C and it gives me all zeroes (?)

Comment: I had the data in column A, the formula in column B. The argument to `indirect` is built from calls to `column` and `row`, so the parts where it says `column() - 1` are telling `indirect` to look 1 column to the left.